# IBM websphere commerce search(SOLR) boost by sales and click through

Tags: java, solr, commerce, wcs

I am trying to boost the solr search using sales and click through of the items in websphere commerce 7.

Ex - 2 items in the document -

1. Item - XYZ red towel, sales - 10 items, click through - 10 times
2. Item - ABC red towel, sales - 9 items, click through - 10 times

When some one searches red towel in the website. I want the ABC red towel to come first in the search result.

Can i Configure this in Management centre tool?

Comment: First, what you call click through is just the count of clicks or the rate count/impressions / ( the latter should be preferred where possible).

I am not sure about this iBM websphere product, but if you have control over Solr you can :
1) store these values in specific fields in the Solr document, update them from time to time and boost results based on those values

2) develop a Solr plugin that modify the way the scorer works, fetching the clicks/sales data from your data source and using them to re-rank the top K results.

It is anyway not a simple matter

Comment: @AlessandroBenedetti cant he sort on those fields(if they are numeric) to get the desired order?

Comment: If he just doesn't care about other factors ( such as Lucene original score), yes, it could use the query to match and then just sort by those numerical values